# How to Fetch Last string using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, string

Let's say I have a string like this

```
Hello World, I am xyz, How are you ?
```

And I need all the characters in the string that comes **after last comma**. Which is here

```
How are you?
```

How can I do this ?

**Note : Here space in the beginning should not come.**

Also I need the remaining string into another variable which will be

```
Hello World, I am xyz
```

**Note: here comma in the end should not come.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with a simple regex:

```
s   = 'Hello World, I am xyz, How are you ?';
hay = s.replace(/.*,/, '');
// " How are you ?"
```

Or, if you want to take care of the leading space at the same time:

```
s   = 'Hello World, I am xyz, How are you ?';
hay = s.replace(/.*,\s*/, '');
// "How are you ?"
```

If you want the first part and the "How are you ?" part, then you could use [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) instead of [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

```
var m = s.match(/^(.*),\s*(.*)$/);
// m[1] is "Hello World, I am xyz"
// m[2] is "How are you ?"
```

Comment: ok gr8, & what if I want to get the remaining string without comma or any space in the end ?

Comment: @aslamdoctor: I've added an update for that. You might want to ask Jayendra Patil or f0x for a straight string manipulating solution too.

Answer (score 2):

you can do with normal javascript -

```
var a= "Hello World, I am xyz, How are you ?"
alert(a.substring(a.lastIndexOf(',')+1,a.length));
```

Comment: @RobG: I thought a regex was the obvious answer so I gave them a +1 for the first non-regex solution.

Comment: @mu - RegExp is OK but string methods are a lot faster, so IMHO preferred in simple cases.

Comment: @RobG: Sometimes faster for the machine but not necessarily for the programmer. A simple regex is often clearer than a pile of non-regex string wrangling; and sometimes going for a regex turns one problem into two problems. The difference rarely matters at all in simple cases.

Comment: I'd probably do it as `s.replace(/.+,\s*/,'')` to deal with spaces after the comma, but the OP didn't stipulate that so the simple string method works for me. :-)

Answer (score 1):

No jquery required but i would use the trim function in conjunction with the following:

```
var str = 'Hello World, I am xyz, How are you ?'

jQuery.trim(str.substring(str.lastIndexOf(',') + 1));
```

Comment: You're using jQuery to trim a possibly non-existant space after the comma? If that is an issue for the OP, then a RegExp will do: `s.replace(/.+,\s*/,'')`. Ta da! Saved 4,000 lines of code!

Comment: "poosibly"? it exists in the OP's example. +1 Noddy badge for your comment though. ;)

Comment: The OP didn't ask to trim it, though it was trimmed in the example. 50-50 bet? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

you dont really need jquery for that, maybe just for the CSS-selector to find the text, but you can use normal Javascript like split and splice to find the last text: http://jsbin.com/ibugob/2/edit

Answer (score 0):

Don't think it can be done with jQuery, but simple Javascript will do the trick.

```
var phrase = "Hello World, I am xyz, How are you ?";
var splitPhrase = phrase.split(",");

var lastElement = splitPhrase[splitPhrase.length - 1];
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript strings actually have a .split() function, so you won't need jquery at all:

```
var str = "Hello world, I am xyz, How are you?";
var parts = str.split(",");

// That just gave you an array
// ...Now find the last element:
var result = parts[parts.length - 1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably, like this also.

```
var a = "Hello World, I am xyz, How are you ?"
alert(a.split(',')[2]);
```